# Can you cross at any border into Mexico after legalizing your car from the US?

Tags: mexico

Once you pick up your paperwork in the US to legalize a car in Mexico can you cross into mexico at any border?

Comment: Are you an American citizen?

Comment: I am not sure what is the concern?  Are you concerned about legality of driving a Mexico Registered Car into the US or whether or you're able to cross the border?